# Graph axis label rotation

Tags: tikz-pgf

I thought

```
ylabel style={rotate=-90}
```

would prevent my y-axis rotation but it is still happening for some reason.
It seems that the grid lines are still going through the tick labels even after I put

```
fill=white
```

Below is my code:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newtheorem{theorem}{THEOREM}
\newtheorem{proof}{PROOF}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart,shapes.geometric,calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations,babel,patterns,fit}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\newenvironment{tightcenter}{
\setlength\topsep{0pt}
\setlength\parskip{0pt}
\begin{center}}{\end{center}}
\begin{document}
% !TeX spellcheck = en_GB 
\tikzset{%
insert new path/.style={%
insert path={%
node[midway,sloped]{\tikz \draw[#1,thick] (-.2pt,0) -- ++(.2 pt,0);}
}
}
}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines=middle,
grid=major,
%ticks=none,
xmin=-3,
xmax=70,
ymin=-3,
ymax=70,
xtick={0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,65,70},
ytick={0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,65,70},
height=11cm,
width=13cm,
axis line style={shorten >=-10pt, shorten <=-10pt},
ylabel style={
fill=white,
yshift=10pt,
rotate=-90
},
ylabel=Y LABEL,
xlabel style={
xshift=10pt,
fill=white
},
xlabel=X,
ylabel near ticks,
xlabel near ticks,
]
\node[below] at (axis cs:-1.5,0) {$O$};
\draw[fill=black](axis cs:50,45) circle (3pt);
\addplot[thick,color=black,samples=100,domain=0:70] {3*x+3.739};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

and the output is

[image: output]

Can anyone please suggest where have I gone wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You are simply confusing `ylabel style` and `yticklabel style`, I think.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you need to distinguish between `ylabel style` and `yticklabel style`. I also moved `ylabel style={rotate=-90},` down to make it work. It has to be below `ylabel near ticks,` since otherwise the rotation gets overwritten (or is not yet defined).

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newtheorem{theorem}{THEOREM}
\newtheorem{proof}{PROOF}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart,shapes.geometric,calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations,babel,patterns,fit}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\newenvironment{tightcenter}{
\setlength\topsep{0pt}
\setlength\parskip{0pt}
\begin{center}}{\end{center}}
\begin{document}
% !TeX spellcheck = en_GB 
\tikzset{%
insert new path/.style={%
insert path={%
node[midway,sloped]{\tikz \draw[#1,thick] (-.2pt,0) -- ++(.2 pt,0);}
}
}
}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines=middle,
grid=major,
%ticks=none,
xmin=-3,
xmax=70,
ymin=-3,
ymax=70,
xtick={0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,65,70},
ytick={0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,65,70},
height=11cm,
width=13cm,
axis line style={shorten >=-10pt, shorten <=-10pt},
yticklabel style={
fill=white,
%yshift=10pt,
},
ylabel=Y LABEL,
xticklabel style={
%xshift=10pt,
fill=white
},
xlabel=X,
ylabel near ticks,
xlabel near ticks,
ylabel style={rotate=-90},
]
\node[below] at (axis cs:-1.5,0) {$O$};
\draw[fill=black](axis cs:50,45) circle (3pt);
\addplot[thick,color=black,samples=100,domain=0:70] {3*x+3.739};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, super knowledgeable and helpful as always. Your code is very simple and tidy!

Answer (score 3):

Based on @marmot's answer and just for fun (though it is quite ugly) a small animation to see the effect of the `rotate` option

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newtheorem{theorem}{THEOREM}
\newtheorem{proof}{PROOF}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart,shapes.geometric,calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations,babel,patterns,fit}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\newenvironment{tightcenter}{
\setlength\topsep{0pt}
\setlength\parskip{0pt}
\begin{center}}{\end{center}}
\usepackage{animate}

\begin{document}
% !TeX spellcheck = en_GB 
\tikzset{%
insert new path/.style={%
insert path={%
node[midway,sloped]{\tikz \draw[#1,thick] (-.2pt,0) -- ++(.2 pt,0);}
}
}
}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\begin{center}
\begin{animateinline}[controls,loop]{3}
  \multiframe{72}{ixb=0+15}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines=middle,
grid=major,
%ticks=none,
xmin=-3,
xmax=70,
ymin=-3,
ymax=70,
xtick={0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,65,70},
ytick={0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,65,70},
height=11cm,
width=13cm,
axis line style={shorten >=-10pt, shorten <=-10pt},
yticklabel style={
fill=white,
%yshift=10pt,
rotate=\ixb
},
ylabel=Y LABEL,
xticklabel style={
%xshift=10pt,
fill=white,
rotate=\ixb
},
xlabel=X,
ylabel near ticks,
xlabel near ticks,
ylabel style={rotate=0},
]
\node[below] at (axis cs:-1.5,0) {$O$};
\draw[fill=black](axis cs:50,45) circle (3pt);
\addplot[thick,color=black,samples=100,domain=0:70] {3*x+3.739};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{animateinline}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

slightly modified nice [marmot's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/121799/marmot) answer (differences are indicated in code by `% <---`):

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
%removed all not related definitions and packages
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}               % <---

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
height=11cm, width=13cm,
restrict y to domain=0:70,              % <---
domain=0:70,                            % <---
samples=141,                            % <---
no marks,                               % <---
clip=false,                             % <---
% some fine-tuning for the display:
xmin=0, xmax=70,
ymin=0, ymax=70,
xtick={0,5,...,70},                     % <---
ytick={0,5,...,70},                     % <---
grid,
axis lines=center,                      % <---
axis line style={shorten >=-10pt, shorten <=-10pt},
ylabel=Y LABEL,
xlabel=X,
ylabel near ticks,
xlabel near ticks,
ylabel style={rotate=-90},
]
\addplot +[ultra thick] {3*x+3.739};    % <---
\node[below left] at (0,0) {$O$};       % <---
\fill   (50,45) circle (3pt);           % <---
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]